# Can I use E.L in myBatis result map?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I have a file x-dao.xml, which contains a **SELECT** query, and a corresponding **ResultMap**, of type *HashMap*.

This is a part of a **spring** app, I have seen EL being used to retrieve values, from parameter maps sent to a Mapper interface, in **select**, **insert** tags. Is the same possible for resultmaps?

Basically, I want to use EL in the resultMap result tag's **property** attribute, to insert values dynamically... is this possible?